# Is there any flutter camera package that supports live camera switching during a video record, that works for IOS and Android

Tags: flutter

Is there any flutter camera package that supports live camera switching during a video record, that works for IOS and Android. I Tried the regular camera plugin for flutter and it doesn't support it out of the Box. And the camerawesome package only supports liveswitching for IOS.

Comment: did you get any options?

Comment: Nope, I did not

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a PR for it https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/6478. You could use that PR's branch before it is merged